# How to embed numeric string in text in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to copy and paste thousands of numeric values, from A2-A10000 to B2-B10000, with some text around it.  Here is one example:

A2:

```
5047612445
```

B2 then needs to be:

```
http://www.example.com/images/5047612445.jpg
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to transform A2: "$" to “http://[…]/$.jpg”, then put this command in B2:

```
="http://www.example.com/images/" & A2 & ".jpg"
```

(Note that extra spaces are shown here in the formula for readability but aren't necessary.)

Comment: Note that this is a dynamic solution; if you subsequently change the value in `A42`, then the URL in `B42` will automatically change correspondingly.  If that's what you (vik3d) want, then fine.  If you want a static solution, where the `B` values are permanent (except when changed directly), there's an additional step (actually, two steps): select Column `B`, and then, from the Paste menu, select "Paste Values".  (Or choose "Paste Special" from the menu, and then select "Values".)

Comment: Oops. ⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠

Comment: Note that this is a dynamic solution; if you subsequently change the value in `A42`, then the URL in `B42` will automatically change correspondingly.  If that’s what you (vik3d) want, then fine.  If you want a static solution, where the `B` values are permanent (except when changed directly), there’s an additional step (actually, three steps): select Column `B`, Copy it, and then, from the Paste menu, select “Paste Values”.  (Or choose “Paste Special” from the menu, and then select “Values”.)